# I need receive the messages created in response texts in some intentions of the API.AI

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

My issue:

[I have two responses, but my chat return only one specified "the speech", but i need that return the two, like do the console of api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcgKA.png)

example of response JSON from API:

{
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-12T20:08:48.101Z",
  "lang": "es",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Hello how are you?",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "intent",
        "parameters": {},
        "lifespan": 1
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "welcome"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Hello!",
      **"messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Hello!"
        },
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Bye!"
        }
      ]**
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": ""
}

I need show the black messages.

Comment: I didn't understand if you need this:
var obj = JSON.parse(val);
var response = obj.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech;

Comment: That's it but I realized that the api does not send the text responses as it does in the test console, inside the interface where you create and configure the agents and intents, ie if I have more than one text response answer Which sends me api.ai is a response and not the two joined. In this case although I want to choose the message or speech to show the api sends me only one ...